# Partitioning Hard drive

Tags: partitioning

I will be converting from WindowsXP to Ubuntu in a couple weeks.  During the installation process, will 12.04.4 ask me what size of the partition I want to create?  Is it necessary to create a partition?  When I last installed WindowsXP on my laptop, I did not create a partition.

This is my laptop.  A Toshiba 1.60Ghz with 1.96GB RAM Pentium(R)M.  So again, if I create a partition size would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 0):

Is good to create 3 partition:

- root [mount point / ]
- home [mount point /home ]
- swap [ mount point swap ]

Why? On root partition will be you system aka installation of OS and application. On home will be you data like user on system. This two partition is separated because in some cases when you will to change version on will to do fresh install your data will be safe on separate partition. Swap will help your ram memory.
You don't specify hdd size but for system is enough 20 GB, for swap 2x ram mem size in your case 4 GB. The rest is for your data aka /home partition

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is necessary to create a partition if one does not exist

The XP installer will of created a partition for you. 
The Ubuntu installer will give you the option to create or reuse partitions.
You won't need to manually create any partitions before installing Ubuntu.

I recommend the defaults unless you have good reason to not use them, which will create a root partition for all your files and a swap partition for memory management.